# Prevent user registration with ServiceStack.OpenId

Tags: authentication, servicestack

Is it possible to prevent ServiceStack from registering new users with the OpenId providers? (Registration Module disabled)

I only want to enable OpenId for users that already exists in the IUserAuthRepository, but ServiceStack adds every unknown user automatically.